# How to apply a regex to a folder full of .txt files?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, io

I have this regex:

```
regex_ = r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VMP\w+)'
```

I would like to apply it to a folder full of txt files and return every document as a list with and a new line. something like this:

```
[pattern of the regex 1]
[pattern of the regex 2]
...
[pattern of the regex n]
[pattern of the regex n-1]
```

So this is what I tried:

```
directory_ = '/Users/user/path/folder_txts/'
regex_ = r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VMP\w+)'

def retrive(directory, a_regex):
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.txt')):
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            important_stuff = re.findall(a_regex, file.read())
            my_list = [tuple([j.split()[0] for j in i]) for i in important_stuff]
            print my_list
```

and this is the output:

```
print retrive(directory_, regex_)
['']
['']
...
['']
```

Which is wrong since the output should look like this:

```
[('string', 'string', 'string'), ('string', 'string', 'string')]
[('string', 'string', 'string'), ('string', 'string', 'string')]
...
[('string', 'string', 'string'), ('string', 'string', 'string')]
```

How can I apply the above regex to the whole txt files of the directory and return them as lists alphabetically sorted by the name it's name file?. [This](http://pastebin.com/EayfmyeK) is an example of one txt file.

Comment: Your regular expression is wrong. What exactly do you want to extract?

Comment: For example.. for the txt file example this is the output that I want:`[('no', 'estar', 'lavar'), ('no', 'haber', 'sorprender')]`. I guess is not wrong since I do [this](http://pastebin.com/vdByTXtV) and the regex is extracted. thanks for the help!

Comment: Your regex requires the substrings `RN`, `VA` and `VMP` to always be present in the lines to be matched, and they would be part of the output because they are included in the capturing groups. Show us an excerpt of the files you expect to match, otherwise it's impossible for us to debug the regex.

Comment: For example for this [file](http://pastebin.com/EayfmyeK) I would like to extract only the second word of the list from left to right that has as id `RN`, `VA`, `VMP` that ocurre one after another in this order: `RN`, `VA`, `VMP`  for example for the txt sample i this will be the desired output:`[('no', 'estar', 'lavar'), ('no', 'haber', 'sorprender')]` which preserves the order I mention before, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If I am not clear let me know guys. Thanks!

Comment: Provide a text sample, please.

Comment: [here is](http://pastebin.com/EayfmyeK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi something has been wrong in your regex.

Please provide

```
regex_ = r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VM\w+)'
```

instead of

```
regex_ = r'(\w+\s+RN).*?(\w+\s+VA\w+).*?(\w+\s+VMP\w+)'
```

and in function

```
important_stuff = re.findall(a_regex, file.read(), re.S)
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works!... What can I do if I want this: `RN`, `VA`,`VMP`. How can I modify the previous regex?. Thanks!